# Wordpress get post id with matched post content

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way in `Wordpress` so that I would generate a `sub-string` of a post content and it would give me the post id?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking about excerpt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using awesome WP Query Class of WordPress with search parameter. e.g. Following query will search for  any posts with "hello" words in it and display its Post Ids as you needed:

```
<?php
     // 's' parameter is for search
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 's' => 'hello' ) );

       if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
          while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
              $the_query->the_post();
     //now we can echo anything we want like e.g. IDs
              echo get_the_ID();
        }

       } else {
                 // no posts found
       }
         /* Restore original Post Data */
         wp_reset_postdata();

 ?>
```